# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Home Improvement breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0         26
Users destroyed                                 150          0
User banned from review                           1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            41      1,617
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                7        184
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        394      1,924
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                3      1,786
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                10      7,145
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               93      4,448
Tag synonyms proposed                             1          0
Tag synonyms created                              1          0
Questions reopened                                8          4
Questions protected                               6        155
Questions migrated                               19          0
Questions merged                                  1          0
Questions flagged⁴                               15        478
Questions closed                                216        961
Question flags handled⁴                         170        323
Posts unlocked                                    0          5
Posts undeleted                                  22         49
Posts locked                                      1        262
Posts deleted⁵                                1,588      2,020
Posts bumped                                      0      8,731
Escalations to the CM team                        3          0
Comments undeleted                               13          0
Comments flagged                                 23      1,502
Comments deleted⁶                             1,486      3,110
Comment flags handled                           672        853
Answers flagged                                 160      3,342
Answer flags handled                          3,165        337
All comments on a post moved to chat             12          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...